# PHP form not validating form field properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I'm learning some more PHP and after PHP itself to work, I can't seem to get it to validate any form field correctly. My goal is to check if the firstname field is empty, and if it is, it will give a message in a red color. The message in the red works, but only because the echo script is being called by the form submission, not because it has detected any empty field, because when I made an else statement to say "wassup" if its not empty, I got the same message for when the field is empty. Also, is there a way to check off multiple input fields at once like you could with JavaScript? For example if input1 == '' || input2 == '' and so on. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal Info</legend>
First name <input name="name" type="text"> 
Middle name <input name="middlename" type="text"> 
Surname <input name="lastname" type="text">  
Age <input name="age" type="number"> 
Date of birth <input name="dob"  type="date">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Regional & location info</legend>
Continent 
<select>
<option value="europe">Europe</option>
<option value="americas">America</option>
<option value="africa">Africa</option>
<option value="asia">Asia</option>
<option value="australia">Australia</option>
<option value="eurasia">Eurasia</option>
</select>
Country <input name="country" type="text"> State <input type="text"> 
City <input name="city" type="text">
Street number <input name="streetno" type="number"> 
Street name <input name="streetname" type="text"> <br><br>
Suburb <input name="suburb" type="text"> Postcode <input name="postcode" type="number"> 
If none of these apply to your accommodations, enter a typed location here <input  type="text">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Previous lifestyle accommodations</legend>
Previous &/or most recent job title <input name="job" type="text"> 
First   time job seeker <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="ftjb"> 
I'm a student <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="ias"> 
Previous &/or most recent acedemic title <input name="school" type="text"> 
First time applying for a qualification <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="ftafaq"> 
I have work experience <input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="ihwe">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Details of arrival</legend>
Reason for arrival <input name="reason" type="text"> 
Date of arrival <input name="arrival" type="date"> 
Amount of stay expectancy 
<input type="checkbox" name="check3">Temporary 
<input type="checkbox" name="check4">Longterm
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Signiture</legend>
<input name='signiture' type="text"> 
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$suburb = $_POST['suburb'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$streetno = $_POST['streetno'];
$streetname = $_POST['streetname'];
$suburb = $_POST['suburb'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$school = $_POST['school'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
$signiture = $_POST['signiture'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST[$firstname])) {
        echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center">Your first name is required</p>';
    } else {
        echo "wassaup";
    }
}





?>
```

Comment: i would suggest to put jquery validations here for form validation.

Comment: pls check this thread : https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/akPoad

Comment: @prakashtank _“i would suggest to put jquery validations here for form validation”_ - client-side validation is never a replacment for server-side validation, at most it is an option extra for user convenience.

Comment: @04FS : yes i mean to put both kind of validation client side as well as server side

Answer (score 0):

change this `if (empty($_POST[$name])) {` to `if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {` and check again. your syntax is wrong that's why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you need to do this:

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {    //Or replace $_POST['name'] with $firstname
    echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center">Your first name is required</p>';
} else {
    echo "wassaup";
}
```

Comment: Ok it works, now how do I check multiple fields at once like I mentioned?

Comment: In backend or in frontend? If you are asking for PHP, just add the next condition in the if statement for e.g.: if (empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['lastname']) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax `if (empty($_POST[$firstname]))`. You should use ' ' single paranthesis in `firstname` and remove this sign $.

Comment: It's working now, I just need to figure out how to do multiple fields at once like I wrote about in the question.

Comment: @Fico I am not that good in PHP but I will try and see if I can do that. If my answer has fixed your first problem please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your code

```
if (!isset($_POST['firstname'] || empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
    echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center">Your first name is required</p>';
  } else {
    echo "wassaup";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create error array where you will put all yours errors

```
$error = array();
```

then when you check for multiple fields

```
if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) $error[] = "First name can't be empty";
if (empty($_POST['lastname'])) $error[] = "Last name can't be empty";
// and so on
```

after you do all of this make statement to check if error array is empty, if not display errors

```
if (empty($error)) {
   // do something
} else {
   // error exists you want to display all errors
   foreach ($error as $value) {
       echo '<ul><li>'.$value.'</li></ul>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the html form, you have to add the attribute required in html tag and without using the PHP processing

```
First name <input name="name" type="text" required="required">
```

and if the user doesn't enter his First name, he will get the error message (that the first name is required)